# Problema migrando una aplicación de windows server 2003 x86 a windows server 2012 x64

Tags: c#, c++, .net

Estoy migrando una aplicación *aspx* escrita en `C#` desde ***Windows Server 2003 x86*** a ***Windows Server 2012 X64***. Esta aplicación incluye una librería que consume la *SDK* de *Host Integration Server 2009* desarrollada en `C++` llamada `CallLU0.dll` . Esta librería originalmente estaba compilada para *X86* pero debido a la imposibilidad de instalar la *SDK* de *HIS X86* sobre el servidor la hemos recompilado en *X64*. Una vez recompilada, hemos registrado la *DLL* y hemos añadido la referencia a la solución. Esta referencia se añade como tipo interoperable creando una clase `CallLU0lib.DLL` . La aplicación donde la añado esta escrita en `C#` y la compilamos como a*ny CPU*. En tiempo de ejecución, justo al instanciar la clase de esta `DLL` nos arroja la siguiente excepción:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {EB02C4C5-8FAF-4E66-9176-5C6881F7D198} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

LLevamos varios días tratando de probar nuevas soluciones.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

Comment: Si CallLU0.dll  es una dll de 64 bits, "any CPU" sólo podría ser en 64 bits. Yo limitaría la búsqueda compilando sólo para 64 bits. Y ah, por supuesto, miraría yo mismo cómo regsvr32 no muestra ningún mensaje de error...

Comment: Como dice @asdasdasd Prueba [con la siguiente respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1496238/5622844), a ver si funciona.

Comment: Hemos compilado solo para 64 bits pero hay otras dll que solo existen en 32 bits y son totalmente necesarias para la aplicación por tanto no funcionan. ¿Cómo miro por qué no muestra ningun error regsvr32 ?
Muchas gracias!

Comment: Oh, quise decir que ejecutaría nuevamente regsvr32 para registrar la dll, por si hubiera ocurrido algún error que pasó inadvertido la primera vez.

Comment: Hemos probado de nuevo varias veces incluso tratando de registrar una version de 32 bits con SYSWOW64 y no conseguimos nada. Nos da error

Comment: En Visual Studio sigue estos pasos: - propiedades del proyecto-> en la pestaña Generar(Bluid) -> plataforma objetivo = X86. Suerte! ;)